# How to add post page pagination to template part?

Tags: pagination, navigation, get-posts, paginate-links

How can I get this page to display the post page pagination? I'm using a custom blog template with a get_template_part.

https://www.nowitconnects.com/blog/

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying blog content in page_blog.php
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package nowitconnects
 */
?>
<!-- blogs ================================================== -->
<section class="">
    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- START BLOG LOOP -->
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) ); 
            while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                    <div class="aside-feature">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="">
                                <?php // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));
                                } ?><br/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <?php the_title( '<h3><a href="'.get_permalink( $id ).'">', '</a></h3>' ); ?>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?><br/><hr/><br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?> <!-- END BLOG LOOP -->
            <aside id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
            </aside><!-- #secondary -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The blog shouldn't be a page template. You should set a page for posts in Settings > Reading and then make sure an appropriate template from the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) exists. That template should use [the main loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/). Then pagination will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Right after the endwhile line, try adding...

```
<?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
```

[more info on the_posts_pagination()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_posts_pagination)

Comment: thank you. added this below the endwhile in the content-blog.php file with no luck!?